# Magento 1.7.0.2 admin (unable to click/edit in row in CMS/Pages, CMS/Block ... Roles/Users)

Tags: javascript, magento, admin

I cannot go inside (click/edit) any page, block, user, etc. like here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qbu4gk0dqhfumt/Zrzut%20ekranu%202015-04-20%2017.40.00.png?dl=0).

Title in  is not generated (https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxzsmzx6k48smnb/Zrzut%20ekranu%202015-04-20%2017.47.09.png?dl=0) and i cannot modify nothing.

Unfortunately, I don't know when it happend.

I've tried to fix permissions, replace 'js' and admin template folders, turn off cache and delete 'var' folder but still not working.

Do you have any ideas what to do?
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. Some magento files (css/js) are missed or have incorrect permissions (unable to read)
2. Some 3rd party extension installed and broke admin area (js conflict as example).

Can you open js console in browser and check for errors?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any error in console i checked before was writing this topic.

1. I installed core magento css and js files again in "js" and "skin" folders.
2. I didnt install new 3rd party extension from year and problem has been started 3 weeks ago.